# Highcharts won't show up on my page

Tags: highcharts

I have a page that needs to load a graph using hightcharts. I just wonder why it doesn't work on any browser.

I have a sample code in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/colt25/ttyhtqL8/.

$(function () {
          $("#container").highcharts({

```
          chart: {
              type: "line"

          },
          title: {
              text: "'.$tyear.' TAF"
          },
          xAxis: {
              categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
          },
          yAxis: {
            min: 0,
              title: {
                  text: ""
              }
          },
          plotOptions: {
              line: {
                  dataLabels: {
                      enabled: true
                  },
                  enableMouseTracking: false
              }
          },
          series: [{
              name: "Count per Month",
              data: [';`enter`enter code here` code here`
```

Comment: you are missing the references in fiddle

Comment: It looks like a part of code. Could you update the demo with your current code and hardcoded data? Please run the console (developer tools in a browser) and let me know what kind of errors do you have.